# Datamapper and CI: is not a valid parent relationship

Tags: php, codeigniter, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

I have 2 models from tables I need to relate,
campus:

```
class Campus extends Datamapper {

    var $table='campi';
    var $has_many=array('boleto');    

    function __construct()  {
        parent::__construct();  
    }
}
```

And boleto:

```
class Boleto extends Datamapper {

    var $table='boletos';
    var $has_one=array('campus');  

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    } 
}
```

I have been working with these tables 5 months, even have the relation table:

```
| id | boleto_id | campus_id |
```

Everything was ok, but recently, every time I need to make something that includes that relation I got this error message:

> DataMapper Error: 'boleto' is not a valid parent relationship for
>   Campus. Are your relationships configured correctly?

Do somebody know what's happening? I can't find the error. The strange is that, as I said, it was working.

Thanks in advance!

Table `boletos`:

```
| id | folio |
```

Table `campi`:

```
| id | nombre_campus |
```

Table `boletos_campi`:

```
| id | boleto_id | campus_id |
```

I'm trying with this code (as it was working before I already have the relation saved):

```
$b = new Boleto();
$b->where('id',20114)->get();
$b->campus->get();
```

Comment: Can you show us that line where the error generating relation usage occurs? Also, the two table schema in question (boletos, campi) could be helpful too. You can just edit the question and add those too.

Comment: The error comes in `$b->campus->get();` .

Comment: This is strange, i can't seem to reproduce the problem with these snippets, it's just generates a query like: `SELECT \`campi\`.*
FROM (\`campi\`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN \`boletos_campi\` boletos_campi ON \`campi\`.\`id\` = \`boletos_campi\`.\`campus_id\`
WHERE \`boletos_campi\`.\`boleto_id\` =  1`. I would try to identify the change that broke the stuff, reading back on commit diffs can help.

Comment: The problem is that it was working 5 months, I didn't change anything, and now it does not work :/ Thanks!!